# how to retrieve an element from a list of .map react elements with a single click

Tags: reactjs, loops, arraylist, freeze, react-dom

I'm trying to retrieve the selected item by clicking on it in an item list. To do this, I've tried using a variable that I change on click, but on click the page freezes without any error.

cards.js

```
import Card from "./card";
import React, { useState } from 'react';


export default function Cards (props){

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [card, setCard] = useState({});


        const handleClick = (card) => {
            console.log(card);
            setCard(card);
            setOpen(true);
        }

    return(
        <ul className='cards__items'>
            {props.cards.map(card => (
                <Card card={card} key={card.cardId} handleClick={handleClick}/>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

card.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Logo from './logo';


export default function Card(props){
    return(  
        <li className='cards__item' key={props.card.cardId} onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.card)}>
            <div className='cards__item__left'>
                <div className='cards__item__logo'>
                    <Logo type={props.card.card_type} locked={props.card.status}/>
                </div>
                <div className='cards__item__info'>
                    <p className='cards__item__type'>{props.card.card_type==='VIRTUAL' ? 'Virtuelle' : props.card.card_type==='PHYSICAL' ? 'Physique':(props.card.card_type).toCapitalizeCase()}</p>
                    <p className='cards__item__maskedPan'>{props.card.maskedPan.slice(8,16)}</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className='cards__item_right'>
                    <div className='cards__item__user'>
                    <span className='cards__item__name'>{(props.card.deliveryAddress.deliveryFirstname).toLowerCase() + " " + (props.card.deliveryAddress.deliveryLastname).toLowerCase()}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='cards__item__money'>
                    <div className='cards__item__solde'>
                    <div className='cards__item__money__left'>
                        <p className='cards__item__money__value'>{props.card.cardStats.totalPaymentMonth} €</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='cards__item__money__right'>
                        <p className='cards__item__money__value'>{props.card.cardLimits.limitPaymentMonth} €</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='cards__item__progress__bar'/>
                <div className='cards__item__progress__bar__fill' style={{width: props.card.cardStats.totalPaymentMonth/props.card.cardLimits.limitPaymentMonth*100 + '%', backgroundColor: props.card.cardStats.totalPaymentMonth/props.card.cardLimits.limitPaymentMonth*100 > 90 ? '#E6492D' : props.card.cardStats.totalPaymentMonth/props.card.cardLimits.limitPaymentMonth*100 > 75 ? '#F69E2F' : '#50AD87'}}/>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </li>
        

    )
}
```

I think it comes from an infinite loop, but I don't see how else to do it.
someone already had this problem and solved it ?

I tested the useContext , useState and a local variable